# Bind the height of a Polygon to the StackPanel height

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, expression-blend

I can't figure how to bind the height of a polygon to the height of my stack panel.

If I wanted to add a rectangle, all I had to do is something like that:

```
                     <Rectangle Width="75" >
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
```

This one won't brake the height of the panel. but with the polygon it seems like I can't leave some of the points as blank so that will scale with the parent panel.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your polygon with a `<Viewbox>`.

The `Viewbox` automatically scales its content to its size. Exactly how it does so can be tweaked with the `Stretch` and `StretchDirection` properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ross, I'm afraid I don't understand how to accomplish that. I took the Polygon sample from MSDN and warped it with a ViewBox with StretchDirection="UpOnly". the polygon still brake the height size of the parent stackpanel.

If you could provide a sample code of your implementation it will be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this solution works too

[image]

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="TextBlock1" Margin="2" />
        <TextBlock Text="TextBlock2" Margin="2" />
        <TextBlock Text="TextBlock3" Margin="2" />
        <TextBlock Text="TextBlock4" Margin="2" />
        <TextBlock Text="TextBlock5" Margin="2" />
      </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Path Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
    Width="50" Stretch="Fill">
      <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
          <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="1,0.5">
            <LineSegment Point="0,0" IsSmoothJoin="True" />
            <LineSegment Point="0,1" IsSmoothJoin="True" />
          </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
      </Path.Data>
    </Path>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. but I will give Ross the V because he already answered and has less reputation.